# Unix Regular Expression in Grep

Tags: unix, grep, expression, output

I have some lists named

```
20131101_klm
20131101_abc
20131102_klm
20131102_abc
.
.
```

First numbers are time stamp like 20131101_klm is klm list in 01.11.2013 and so for abc for everyday.

These list have some lines like

```
abcd
efgh
jk4m
23rf
```

I want to make a search with "grep" command in only **between 09.11.2013 and 16.11.2013** in only ***klm lists***.

(lists are in txt.gz format)
Im writing

```
zegrep -a -E '*abcd*|*defgh*' 201311[09,10,11,12,13,14,15,16]*_klm
```

but it is giving me all november data like in 20131101 - 20131102 so some data coming from not between 20131109 and 20131116. ?? Why it is not only giving between 09-16 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually a shell problem, not a grep problem.

```
zgrep -a -E '*abcd*|*defgh*' 201311{09,10,11,12,13,14,15,16}*_klm
```

This will work in most current shells (mksh, AT&T ksh, csh, tcsh, zsh, GNU bash).

Some shells also support regular expressions, but usually not POSIX ERE.